# Idiomatic way in Redux to trigger dependent state updates

Tags: typescript, redux

Consider the following simple state

```
interface State {
  query: string;
  results: string[];
}
```

So, we have a query and some results. Now, we have to actions:

```
type SetQueryAction = {type: "SET_QUERY", payload: string};
type SetResultsAction {type: "SET_RESULTS", payload: string[]};
```

Upon a user entering a new query, I want to execute a search and display the results. Which of the following two approaches is correct:

1. Have a function updateQuery that dispatches a SetQueryAction and dispatches an async thunked function that executes the query and later dispatches SetResultsAction to update State.
2. Dispatch SetQueryAction, have a listener subscribed to State.query that executes an async thunk function that executes the query and later dispatches SetResultsAction to update State.

So, the main question is: Should I tightly couple the derived state with the query or decouple them using a subscribe-listener.

**EDIT**

Let’s make the example a bit more complicated: set results flow in incrementally and I want to fill the results incrementally, a single query results in a series of SetResultsAction.

So, it’s not “pure” anymore.

Comment: Derived state will be a pure function, which means a subscribe listener can safely derive the state. Additionally, performance can be improved via memoization. I read a good article about just this subject not long ago. If I can find it I may consider adding this as more detailed answer.

Comment: So you prefer option 2. Instead using sucribe, I could also directly dispatch the aync query function within the SET_QUERY reducer. What about that?

Comment: I can't find the article I was referring to earlier, but you may want to take a look at [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: I have read that reselect doesn’t play nice with async.